# How to automate actions performed on the iPhone simulator?

Tags: ios, functional-testing, ios-ui-automation, automated-tests

Right now I am automating tests for an app using UIAutomation class. But my app has certain features which, I believe, can't be tested using just UIAutomation. For example, there is a feature  that if a new contact is added to the addressbook, a popup is shown in the app. To test this feature a new contact needs to be added to the address book the popup should be checked. But UIAutomation automates user actions only within the target app. Can anyone tell me how can I automate these type of actions(preferably using scripts)?

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend you automate with Sikuli. its mucvh easier to record and play. also u can any kind of alerts or popups

Comment: Both your answers so far recommend Sikuli. Are you personally involved with it? If so, please make sure to read and follow our FAQ entry on promotion: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion

Comment: im not here for any promotion. i have used it and i felt it how useful it is when u use it. if dis doesnt work to the user at all then probably he can follow whatever the best it is.